# How to split a file into several tokens

Tags: java, regex, io, token, trim

I was trying to tokenize an input file from sentences into tokens(words).
For example, 
"This is a test file." into five words "this" "is" "a" "test" "file", omitting the punctuations and the white spaces. And store them into an arraylist.
I tried to write some codes like this:

```
public static ArrayList<String> tokenizeFile(File in) throws IOException {
    String strLine;
    String[] tokens;
    //create a new ArrayList to store tokens
    ArrayList<String> tokenList = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (null == in) {
        return tokenList;
    } else {
        FileInputStream fStream = new FileInputStream(in);
        DataInputStream dataIn = new DataInputStream(fStream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dataIn));

        while (null != (strLine = br.readLine())) {
            if (strLine.trim().length() != 0) {

                //make sure strings are independent of capitalization and then tokenize them
                strLine = strLine.toLowerCase();

                //create regular expression pattern to split
                //first letter to be alphabetic and the remaining characters to be alphanumeric or '
                String pattern = "^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9'-]*$";
                tokens = strLine.split(pattern);
                int tokenLen = tokens.length;

                for (int i = 1; i <= tokenLen; i++) {
                    tokenList.add(tokens[i - 1]);
                }
            }
        }
        br.close();
        dataIn.close();
    }
    return tokenList;
}
```

This code works fine except I found out that instead of make a whole file into several words(tokens), it made a whole line into a token. "area area" becomes a token, instead of "area" appeared twice. I don't see the error in my codes. I believe maybe it's something wrong with my `trim()`. 
Any valuable advices is appreciated. Thank you so much.

Maybe I should use scanner instead?? I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

I think Scanner is more approprate for this task. As to this code, you should fix regex, try `"\\s+";`

Comment: Thank you!! Now I know my regular expression is something unusual.

Answer (score 1):

Try pattern as `String pattern = "[^\\w]";` in the same code